# Rails and MySql datetime behaviour

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I just noticed something odd in my Rails application.
When I update a DateTime column with a random value like below code, it automatically generates a wrong DateTime and saves it instead of NULL.

```
user = AdminUser.last
data = {last_sign_in_at: "1234568!"}
user.update_attributes(data)
```

And it generates a query like below:

```
UPDATE `admin_users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '1234-01-01 04:56:02', `updated_at` = '2018-01-24 21:27:50' WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 3
```

Where is that odd DateTime value coming from ? And interestingly it works with that specific random value. Not with something like "invalid!" and "1234568!" .

So is this something to do with MySql or Rails query generation ?
Maybe I am not aware of such things in database, as it is not something I work with regularly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like rails use `Time` library to convert your `1234568!` and if you try that in rails console like `Time.zone.parse('1234568!')` you get back a Time object `Sun, 01 Jan 1234 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` but if you try to do a `Date.parse(1234568!)` it throws you an `ArgumentError: invalid date` error so maybe you can parse using date to avoid that.

Comment: I am not parsing anything. Are you suggesting to parse every DateTime column values, before inserting ? That would be inefficient in my case.

Comment: why do you need to manually update your `last_sign_in_at` value, I guess you are using some sort of authentication/authorization gems like `devise` and that should take care of everything

Comment: That is just an example I tried in console. Actual error was found with some other DateTime column. It happens with all columns of that type.

Comment: In that case you need to validate it yourself, but why would that be inefficient, you could enforce a validation in the model